# Class Inheritance not inheriting as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, refactoring

I have a self-rolled authorization system base on [RC#386](http://railscasts.com/episodes/386-authorization-from-scratch-part-2).  I noticed a lot of duplication between the `GuestPermission` class and the `MemberPermision` class.

```
class GuestPremission < BasePermission
  allow_action :static, [:about, :careers, :contact, :help, :home]
end
```

and

```
class MemberPermission < BasePermission
  allow_action :static, [:about, :careers, :contact, :help, :home]
end
```

Both inherit from `BasePermission`.  I want to refactor the `MemberPermission` class to inherit from `GuestPermission` instead, like this:

```
class GuestPermission < BasePermission
  allow_action :static, [:about, :careers, :contact, :help, :home]
end

class MemberPermission < GuestPermission
  ...
end
```

Ideally, this should reduce the duplication in `MemberPermission` that already is granted to and exists in `GuestPermission`.  However, I get a recursive error: `filter chain haled as :authorize rendered or redirected`.

This usually tells me that the requested controller#action, (in this case `static#home`) hasn't been implicitly authorized.  But in this case, it should be inheriting from `GuestPermission`.

Any ideas on fixing this so that the duplication of permissions isn't necessary?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this, use rails's concern:

```
module Xxx
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern
   included do
      class_eval do
        allow_action :static, [:about, :careers, :contact, :help, :home]    
      end
   end
end

class GuestPremission < BasePermission
  include Xxx
end

class MemberPermission < BasePermission
  include Xxx
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it all trickle down if `MemberPermission < GuestPermission`?  Your solution doesn't really reduce the duplication.